# How to generate image paths for list of items in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Having a list of items I try to assign an image for each of them where file name equals item's id:

```
 private static renderItemsTable(products: Product[]) {

    return <table className='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product view</th>
                <th>Name</th> 
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                {products.map(prod =>
                <tr key={prod.dateCreated}>                      
                    <td> <img src={require('../../Media/Images/ProductImages/' +prod.id +'.png')} alt= {prod.id} /></td>   
                    <td>{prod.name}</td>
               </tr>
                 )}
        </tbody>
    </table>;
}
```

In this case if one of the files does not exist in folder the whole table does not renders.

Answer (score 0):

How about importing the **fs** module and checking if the file exists before rendering the image

```
<td> <img src={require('../../Media/Images/ProductImages/' +prod.id +'.png')} alt= {prod.id} /></td>
```

Like this

```
<td>
    {fs.existsSync('Media/Images/ProductImages/' +prod.id +'.png') && (
        <img src={require('../../Media/Images/ProductImages/' +prod.id +'.png')} alt= {prod.id} />
    )}
</td>
```

Remember that some functions of the fs module require paths from the current working directory, in other words, the directory that was current when you started node

Comment: Trying to import 'fs: '`import * as fs from 'fs';` - got the error "can not find module"

Comment: You need to run: `npm install @types/node --save-dev`